# Minecraft- spawning in a lava lake

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I died in one of my worlds in my house and I respawned in a lava lake. I'm on survival. I'm using Minecraft PC v0.10.2

Comment: Has someone put lava at the spawn since you started?

Comment: I want to say this is a duplicate, but I can't find the original...

Comment: nobody has been on my world since i created it.

Comment: Have **you** put lava at the spawn since you started?

Comment: no but by the spawnpoint there was a pit of lava near though

Comment: is there like a command to respawn somewhere else?

Comment: i was looking around trying to find dirt to possibly build up and im surrounded by cobblestone im trying to get it to let me type again